# ASP.NET MVC - add attribute depend on model variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to set different color (style) for TR element depend on value of DaysTillEvent variable. I have the following code:

```
            string colorOfRecord = String.Empty;
            if (item.DaysTillEvent <= (2*7))
            {
                colorOfRecord = "class=danger";
            }
            else if (item.DaysTillEvent <= (4 * 7))
            {
                colorOfRecord = "class=warning";
            }
```

and then using:

```
<tr @colorOfRecord>...</tr>
```

it works, but code is not "careful". Any more strong way? Maybe via javascript/jQuery? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _but code is not "careful"._? Your doing a conditional check. Whether you do it this way, or using javascript is not really going to make any difference.

Comment: yes, I understand, that in result no matter. I mean under "careful" that more pure html. As I imagine it, View should as more pure html as possible...

Comment: The view in MVC is typically generated with Razor code (C# code running on the server). For example `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty)` which is certainly not _pure html_ so I don't think that's a valid argument. Personally I would have a view model with a property `public string ClassName` which returns the name of the class to use and then `<tr class="@Model.ClassName">` because I prefer to minimize logic in the view, but there is nothing wrong with your approach. More important is that you be consistent.

Comment: I did not say about pure html, I said about "as pure as possible". So, jQuery variant will be more pure, but it can have more potential problems. So, I want to find "the middle" and which variant is more preferred. My opinion, your variant with ClassName is not good, because: 1. Html depends on Controller (designer can't change design, need to recompile the application), 2. attribute "class" is unnecessary for some cases...

Comment: Why is it _more pure_? Which ever way you do it, you still need to access the value of `item.DaysTillEvent` which is a value in your model. Doing this in the controller, or in the view, or in javascript really makes no difference. Your comment that you need to _recompile the application_ makes no sense. The value of `ClassName` in my alternative suggestion depends on the value of your model property.

Comment: because page will not have a computing of server code. I think so why javascript is probably preferred. About Model.ClassName - what sense to create a variable in model class, which is used only on View?

Comment: I am not talking the view model, not the data model.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke you propose to fill Model.ClassName in view or in controller?